# How do we assign an initial value to a lookup field in sharepoint add in?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

```
<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="ProjectNumberLookup">100000</Field>
      <Field Name="DrawingNumberLookup">100000</Field>
      <Field Name="ComponentNumber">100000</Field>
      <Field Name="ComponentName">Power Supply</Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
```

Here, the ProjectNumberLookup and the DrawingNumberLookup are 2 lookup fields. When the app is installed and when I go the the ../Lists/Components/Allitems.aspx, only the 2 non-lookup fields have the initial values. Is there a way that this can be done or none at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value is represented in the format of ID;#Value so Try adding it using ID;#
if it is 1st value then 1;# or 
if its 2nd 2;#
Your XML now should look something like this: I hope it helps!

`<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="ProjectNumberLookup">1;#10000</Field>
      <Field Name="DrawingNumberLookup">1;#100000</Field>
      <Field Name="ComponentNumber">100000</Field>
      <Field Name="ComponentName">Power Supply</Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Is there an MSDN documentation link you can reference?